# Trying Search Console in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-search-console

I am trying to get a response from Search Console REST API by using the following code, where I've already configured the OAuth2.0 authorization.

```
function searchConsoleQuery() {
  var service = getService();

  var apiURL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/[SITE_URL]/searchAnalytics/query';

  var headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken(),
    'contentType':'application/json',
    'startDate':'20019-10-01',
    'endDate':'2019-10-10',
  };

  var options = {
    'payload': JSON.stringify(headers),
    'method' : 'POST',
    'muteHttpExceptions': true
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiURL, options);

  var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  Logger.log(json)

}
```

When I run it, the log returns the following error message:

```
{error={code=401, message=Login Required, errors=[{reason=required, domain=global, locationType=header, location=Authorization, message=Login Required}]}}
```

Please, someone help fixing this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### From:

```
var headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken(),
  'contentType':'application/json',
  'startDate':'20019-10-01',
  'endDate':'2019-10-10',
};

var options = {
  'payload': JSON.stringify(headers),
  'method' : 'POST',
  'muteHttpExceptions': true
};
```

#### To:

```
var payload = {
  'startDate':'2019-10-01',
  'endDate':'2019-10-10',
};

var options = {
  'payload': JSON.stringify(payload),
  'method' : 'POST',
  'muteHttpExceptions': true,
  'headers': {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()},
  'contentType':'application/json'
};
```

#### Note:

- Please modify `20019-10-01` to `2019-10-01`.
- In this modification, it supposes as follows.

  - Your access token can be used for using Search Analytics: query of Search Console APIs API. The scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly` and/or `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters` is included in the scopes for the access token.
  - You have already enabled Search Console APIs at API console.

#### References:

- [Search Analytics: query](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/searchanalytics/query)
- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.